# How to prevent height change during animation using 100% width images in bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

Bootstrap 3 carousel should use fixed-height images during animation.
Carousel is created using code from bootstrap tutorial

```
 <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <a href="124">
                    <img class="carousel-img" src="124" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">
                <a href="123">
                    <img class="carousel-img" src="123" />

                </a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Image widths are set to carousel width using answer from

[How to center image in carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538967/how-to-center-image-in-carousel)

```
.carousel-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

I screen resolution is big and zoom level is small, image height decreases on animation.
How to use fixed height so that content does not jump ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this CSS,

```
.carousel-inner > .item{
   width: 100%;
}
```